# how to implement logout in provider Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have this code

this is a part of my Main

```
runApp(MultiProvider(
providers: [
  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserCertStorage()),
  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AppInfoHandler(context)),
  .
  .
]
```

this is MyApp

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Provider.of<CertHandler>(context, listen: false);
   Provider.of<AppInfoHandler>(context, listen: false).init();
  .
  .
  .

  return MaterialApp(
```

First I need to reset all providers and then init them. how can I do this?

Comment: This is much easier in riverpod, and hopefully will give you the final reason you need to migrate from provider to riverpod.  In riverpod, you just make all the providers that need to be reset to depend on a common "current user" provider.  Then, when you logout or login as someone new, all the providers will reset, and either immediately rebuild if currently watched, or rebuild as needed.

Comment: did you try doing .reset? so you can create a function void resetProviders(BuildContext context){} and in it add all resets Provider.of<UserCertStorage>(context, listen: false).reset();

Comment: @Texv i did something like this but i wanted to see if there is a better way.